# How do I print out all the value my regex could take in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to print all the value a regex could take in bash. How could I do it, knowing the following code doesn't work.

```
regex="^db10300[7-9]$"
for valueofregex in $regex
do
  echo "$valueofregex";
done
```

It should of course print :

```
db103007
db103008
db103009
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this specific regex it would be possible to enumerate the strings that match, but for regex in general this is an impossible (or at least intractable) problem. Take `.*` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are searching for [`brace expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
for value in db10300{7..9}
do
  echo "$value"
done
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' db10300{7..9}`?

Comment: Potentially quite misleading as it's a completely different syntax and will behave totally differently in all but the simplest of cases...

Comment: @TomFenech OTOH that's what you get when you answer an X-Y question with a guess as to the X.

Comment: @kojiro sure :) I guess it's probably worth stating the assumption that is being made explicitly though

Comment: what if my regular expression is much more complicated like `^(db10300[7-9]|db1030[1-2][0-9])_([5-9]|[1-2][0-9])|(db1040([3-9][0-9])|db104100)_([5-9]|[1-2][0-9])$`

Comment: @B_G Please see my comment to your original question. You cannot generalize this in its original form.

Comment: @B_G AFAIK there is no way to do that expect from limited edge cases. For example, what would you expect if the the regex is `.*` ?

Comment: I saw it and I understood that I can't print all the possible combination of the world. Luckily that's not what I'm trying to achieve : I just want something where the number of solution is finite but which is a bit more complicated than the simplest case.

Comment: @B_G *brace expansion* is quite powerful. Probably you can use it. It's hard to say without a real-world example.

Comment: @B_G for the first part it would be `echo {db10300{7..9},db1030{1,2}{0..9}}` .. and so on.

Comment: So have to go with the brace expression. Thanks.